# How to change the color of a cylinder in VB programmatically

Tags: vb.net

I have created a cylinder programmatically via vb on NX, the cylinder is successful, but unfortunately it doesn't change its color. Below is my code, could someone please tell me what's wrong with my code? Or is there any other method which I can change the color of my cylinder?

Thank you very much

````
Imports System
Imports NXOpen
Module Points_01
    Sub Main()
       Dim theSession As Session = Session.GetSession()
       Dim workPart As Part = theSession.Parts.Work
       Dim lw As ListingWindow = theSession.ListingWindow
       lw.Open()
       'create Point3d using the constructor
       Dim myPt1 As New Point3d(0, 0, 0)
       'create center point
       Dim ptObj As Point
       ptObj = workPart.Points.CreatePoint(myPt1)
       ptObj.SetVisibility(SmartObject.VisibilityOption.Visible)
       Dim myVector As Vector3d
       'enter values for vector
       myVector.X = (1)
       myVector.Y = (2)
       myVector.Z = (3)
       'create offset
       Dim myOffset As Offset
       myOffset = workPart.Offsets.CreateOffset(ptObj.Coordinates, myVector, SmartObject.UpdateOption.WithinModeling)
       'create new point offset from first point
       Dim offsetPoint As Point
       offsetPoint = workPart.Points.CreatePoint(myOffset, ptObj, SmartObject.UpdateOption.WithinModeling)
       offsetPoint.RemoveParameters()
       offsetPoint.SetVisibility(SmartObject.VisibilityOption.Visible)
       lw.Close()
' Create circle
Dim curves As NXOpen.CurveCollection = workPart.Curves
Dim center As NXOpen.Point3d
center = New Point3d(0,0,0)
Dim pi as Double =System.Math.PI
Dim twopi As Double = 2*pi
Dim length As Double = 8
Dim axisX = New Vector3d(1,0,0)
Dim axisY = New Vector3d(0,1,0)
Dim circle = workPart.curves.CreateArc(center, axisX, axisY, length, 0, twopi)
Dim ctol = 0.0095 ' Chaining tolerance
Dim dtol = 0.01 ' Distance tolerance
Dim atol = 0.5 ' Angle tolerance
'Create a circular section
Dim circ As NXOpen.Section = workPart.Sections.CreateSection(ctol, dtol, atol)
Dim helpPoint As New NXOpen.Point3d(0,0,0)
Dim nullObj As NXOpen.NXObject = Nothing
Dim noChain As Boolean = False
Dim createMode As NXOpen.Section.Mode = Section.Mode.Create
' Create rules to add the circle to the section
Dim circl As NXOpen.CurveDumbRule = workPart.ScRuleFactory.CreateRuleBaseCurveDumb({circle})
circ.AddToSection({circl}, circle, nullObj, nullObj, helpPoint, createMode, noChain)
Dim builder = workPart.Features.CreateExtrudeBuilder(Nothing)
builder.Section = circ
'Define the direction of the Extrude
Dim origin As New NXOpen.Point3d(0,0,0)
Dim axisZ As New NXOpen.Vector3d(0,0,1)
Dim updateOption = SmartObject.UpdateOption.DontUpdate
builder.Direction = workPart.Directions.CreateDirection(origin, axisZ, updateOption)
builder.Limits.StartExtend.Value.RightHandSide = "0"
builder.Limits.EndExtend.Value.RightHandSide = "500"
Dim extrudeFeature As NXOpen.Features.Extrude = builder.CommitFeature
builder.Destroy
'Get the displayable object of the Extrude feature
Dim bodies As NXOpen.Body() = extrudeFeature.GetBodies
' Change its color
bodies(0).Color = 186 ' Usually red, by default
    End Sub
End Module```
````

Comment: Quote from the manual: "After setting the color, you must call RedisplayObject in order for the change to take effect"

Comment: I just did so, and it worked. Thank you so much for the comment